# Order of element in field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Given a field extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ and some element $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ which is *not* contained within any proper subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, is there a lower bound on the order of $\alpha$?

I understand that the nonzero elements of a finite field form a cyclic group generated by some primitive element $\beta \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. However, if we don't know whether $\alpha$ is primitive, what can we say about its order (without actually computing anything)?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that $\alpha$ is not contained in any proper subfield mean that it is a primitive element for $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Comment: @Quasicoherent I don't believe so. Take $\mathbb{F}_{3^3}$ for instance. Since $\mathbb{F}_3$ is the only proper subfield, there are 24 elements in $\mathbb{F}_{3^3}$ not contained within a proper subfield. The number of primitive elements in $\mathbb{F}_{3^3}$ is $\varphi(3^3-1) = 12$ so they can't all be primitive.

Comment: I see, this is just an unfortunate collision of terminology.  I thought you meant a [primitive element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension#Definition) in the sense of the Primitive Element Theorem, but you mean a generator for the group of units, aka a primitive root mod $n$.

Comment: @Quasicoherent: Correct. It is a bit unfortunate. I have been bumping into this collision so frequently that I edited the finite fields tag wiki to explain it. To no avail I may add :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the fact that $\alpha$ is not contained within any proper subfield, we know it is not fixed by any power of Frobenius, so that the elements $\alpha, \alpha^p, \alpha^{p^2},...,\alpha^{p^{n-1}}$ are all distinct, i.e. there exist $n$ distinct powers of $\alpha$ not equal to the identity, so $\alpha$ must have order greater than $n$.

Comment: I guess it is worth pointing out that this (+1) observation is connected to the existence of so called *optimal normal basis*. When $p=2$, $\alpha$ is of order $n+1$, and the conjugates of $\alpha$ are all its non-trivial powers as in this answer, we get a very efficient implementation of the arithmetic of $\Bbb{F}_{2^n}$ using the normal basis given by $\alpha$. Such implementations of finite field arithmetic are used in crypto.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for any $m\mid n$, the subfield $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ consists of all elements of order dividing $p^m-1$.  So the possible orders of elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ which are not in any proper subfield are all the factors of $p^n-1$ that are not factors of $p^m-1$ for any proper divisor $m$ of $n$.

This gives a simple way to compute the possibilities in any individual case if you're willing to do some integer factoring.  I don't see any simple way to get a general explicit lower bound from this, though.  Using the Frobenius automorphism, as in Quinn Greicius's answer, you can find a lower bound of $n+1$.  This is tight in some cases: for instance, if $p=3$ and $n=4$, then the possibilities are factors of $3^4-1=80$ which are not factors of $3^2-1=8$, and the smallest such factor is $5=n+1$.   But it is often not tight: for instance, it never can be if $n+1$ is divisible by $p$, since $p^n-1$ has no factors which are divisible by $p$.  Or in the case that $n+1$ is prime, it will be tight iff $p$ is a primitive root mod $n+1$ (since that means exactly that $p^n-1$ is divisible by $n+1$ but $p^m-1$ is not for all smaller $m$).

Comment: This is a far quicker (and more insightful) method for making the computations than just checking by hand for an example where the bound is tight. Thanks!